# How to animate one child but not others using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hey guys, I have written this code from the ground up using jQuery (first real jQuery project), and so far, I have some toggle animation. My code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">      
    <div class="featured-img one">
        <img src="media/desktopography.png" alt="Desktopography"/>
    </div><!-- end .featured-img -->

    <div class="featured-img two">
        <img src="media/dancer.png" alt="Dancer"/>
    </div><!-- end .featured-img -->

    <div class="featured-img three">
        <img src="media/tech.png" alt="Tech"/>
    </div><!-- end .featured-img -->

    <div class="featured-img four">
        <img src="media/strawberry-tree.png" alt="Strawberry Tree"/>
    </div><!-- end .featured-img -->

    <div class="featured-img five">
        <img src="media/snow-leopard.png" alt="Snow Leopard"/>
    </div><!-- end .featured-img -->
</div><!-- end #content -->
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.featured-img').toggle(
  function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
          height: "600px",
          marginTop: "-100px"
 }, 500 );
        $(".featured-img > img").animate({ 
          marginTop: "0px"
 }, 500 );
  },
  function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
          height: "150px",
          marginTop: "100px"
 }, 1500 );
        $(".featured-img > img").animate({ 
          marginTop: "-200px"
 }, 1500 );
  }
   );
 });
```

This works fine with one element, BUT it applies the same animation to every element assigned .featured-img on each click. Is there any way I can only animate the element I clicked, without disturbing the other ones at all?

I have tried playing with :not(:animated), and other stuff, but it only made it worse. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page, if you have it available online?  It would be helpful to see what's happening and how the HTML is built.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the other elements to move when one is being animated or that all the elements are being animated each time one is clicked?

Comment: @Frank DeRosa: I have added the HTML to the question, and the work in progress can be found here: http://projects.michalkopanski.com/PHOTOPortfolio/v2/ . Also, how much harder would it be for only one element to be open at a time?

@beggs: Sorry for not being clear on this, I would like for only ONE element to move, and the others stay still, and that would be the element I click.

Thanks to the both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey everyone, after doing some more research, I figured it out. I knew from the beginning that the reason the other objects were animated because the classes were shared throughout. The way to avoid that is to target only the child of the element we clicked using the jQuery child selector `$(this).children()`. You can see the functional demo [here](http://projects.michalkopanski.com/PHOTOPortfolio/v2/). My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.featured-img').toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ 
                height: "593px",
                marginTop: "-100px"
      }, 500 );
            $(this).children().animate({ 
                marginTop: "0px"
      }, 500 );
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ 
                height: "150px",
                marginTop: "100px"
      }, 1500 );
            $(this).children().animate({ 
                marginTop: "-200px"
      }, 1500 );
        }
      );
    });
```

I hope you guys have learned something new. Thanks for all those who helped.